# Match string values in two different DataFrames Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

I have two dataframes (df1, df2) and I would like to create a new column in df1 that indicates if there is a match,likely match or mismatch in the multiple columns between each dataframe.
df1:

```
id  a   b   c   d   name
a1  94  18  10  20  b1
a2  20  18  1   2   b4,b5
a3  21  18  34  32  b2,b3,b4
a4  216 5   56  76  b5
a5  210 5   10  30  b4,b5
```

df2:

```
id  a   b   c   d
b1  94  5   10  20
b2  A150    5   13  45
b3  167 5   4   -1
b4  210 5   40  80
b5  216 5   60  80
```

Basically name is id of df2.
I would like to match name of df1 to id of df2 & bases of following condition create new column.

```
Match : df1['a','b','c','d'] = df2['a','b','c','d']  
likely match : df1['a','b'] = df2['a','b'] & c or d +- 10 is fine
Missmatch: df1['a','b'] = df2['a','b'] but column c & d > +- 10
Missing: df1 record not in df2
```

Result

```
id  a   b   c   d   name    Status
a1  94  18  10  20  b1      Match
a2  20  18  1   2   b2,b3   Missing
a3  21  18  34  32  b2,b3,b4Missing
a4  210 5   10  30  b4,b5   Missmatch
a5  216 5   56  76  b5      Likely
```

Comment: Do you already have something written yourself? This doesn't seem too hard to write (i.e., straightforward), provided you start simple by looping over the individual elements of each `name` cell, and also looping over the four criteria.

Comment: One catch is that is unclear what the type of the `name` column is: a single string, a list of strings, a numpy array of strings, something else? That is, is a `name.split(",")` necessary or not?

Comment: Why, in your resulting dataframe, is row `a4` a mismatch? There is no `a == 210` value in `df2`, so it should be missing. (NB: "mismatch", single 's'. A missmatch would be a match between two unmarried women, or [something else entirely](https://www.google.com/search?q=missmatc) ).

Comment: name.split(",") is necessary. Its alphanumeric, consist of many value but not list

Comment: Hey sorry, it was wrong, corrected it. Please check. Row4 df1.a == df2.a matching but other column values(c,d) are not matching (Gap more than +- 10), so its mismatch

Comment: I would add your first comment (on `name`) to your question; that is clearer than finding that statement in a set of small-sized comments. And please also consider my first comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: If I use `isin` its comparing row to row, still not able to figure how to compare 1 id with all the name & if present then other columns to that row.

Answer (score 0):

You expected result is wrong. You flipped the column values of `df1['id'] == 'a4'` and `df1['id'] == 'a5'` your column names are different. Nevertheless, you can use `np.select`

```
df2['name'] = df1['name'].str.split(',')

conditions = [
    ((df2.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['name'], axis=1)) & (df1[['a','b','c','d']] == df2[['a','b','c','d']]).any(axis=1)),
    ((df1[['a','b']] == df2[['a','b']]).any(axis=1) & (abs(df2[['c','d']] - df1[['c','d']]) <= 10).any(axis=1)),
    ((df1[['a','b']] == df2[['a','b']]).any(axis=1) & (abs(df2[['c','d']] - df1[['c','d']]) >= 10).any(axis=1)),
]

choices = [
    'Match',
    'Likely',
    'Missmatch',
]

df1['Status'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default='Missing')
```

Result:

```
    id  a   b   c   d   name      Status
0   a1  94  18  10  20  b1         Match
1   a2  20  18  1   2   b4,b5      Missing
2   a3  21  18  34  32  b2,b3,b4   Missing
3   a4  216 5   56  76  b5         Likely
4   a5  210 5   10  30  b4,b5      Match
```

Comment: Thank you. Its matching on the bases of index, if I change the position in of rows in any dataframe it gives wrong result. (eg. In df1 first row move to last, it will give missing as status)